# What is happening to the wcf data?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am adding objects sent from a client to a list which is at the service, my issue is this, during debugging I see that as soon as i return from the main service to the client the list turns to 0. It's like the list gets emptied and as soon as the flow of the program returns to the client and then when the client sends data to the service the data are there, as soon as i enter the method of the service the list gets filled with the old data. I would like to access these data from another part of the program but i always see the list empty. Any tips?

Comment: Have you got the **Service Contract** setup **Per Call** (default) or **Per Session** (sounds like what you want to be using)? Is it a singleton? Static? Some code would help us here. Many reasons for what you are seeing but Google "WCF Service Contract Per Session" as I mentioned.

Comment: Can you post your **.config** as well as the part of the code where you apply `[ServiceBehavior]`.

Comment: The list is static and the connection is always open as it is selfhosted in a winforms app. I use this line of code `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] ` so it's single.

Comment: I believe with this service behavior all clients access the same list. Also, as i wrote above as soon as i return to the service the data are there.

Comment: I have added as an answer to clarify what I mean... I have this working as a full sample so hoping it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment you need to setup the `ServiceContract`'s `SessionMode` and also the `ServiceBehavior`'s `InstanceContextMode`. The default `InstanceContextMode` is `PerCall` which means that your list will not be preserved. You need to change it to use `PerSession`. See below for fully working example (.NET 4):

**Service Side Code:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int AddData(string data);

        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetData();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        private readonly List<string> _myList = new List<string>();

        public int AddData(string data)
        {
            _myList.Add(data);
            return _myList.Count;
        }

        public List<string> GetData()
        {
            return _myList;
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Side web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Client Side:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var service = new Service1Client())
            {
                // Add items...
                int itemCount;
                itemCount = service.AddData("Test Item 1");
                Console.WriteLine("Service now holds {0} items", itemCount);
                itemCount = service.AddData("Test Item 2");
                Console.WriteLine("Service now holds {0} items", itemCount);
                itemCount = service.AddData("Test Item 3");
                Console.WriteLine("Service now holds {0} items", itemCount);

                // Get all of the items added...
                List<string> listFromService = service.GetData();
                foreach (var listItem in listFromService)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  * {0}", listItem);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Side app.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:59604/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Note: I had to ensure that `wsHttpBinding` was used as `basicHttpBinding` does **NOT** support sessions.